# Project Euler 9 Solution not giving correct result

Tags: java, algorithm, combinatorics

The problem is:

> A Pythagorean triplet is a set of three natural numbers, a < b < c,
>   for which,
>
> a^2 + b^2 = c^2 For example, 3^2 + 4^2 = 9 + 16 = 25 = 5^2.
>
> There exists exactly one Pythagorean triplet for which a + b + c =
>   1000. Find the product abc.

So using the function tripletP() I think the program generates all the possible combinations of 3 summators for the number 1000.
And the function isTriplet(a,b,c) in this code, never returns true and the value of int product is 0 at the end.
I can't seem to find the flaw in my logic, any help would be appreciated.

Here is my Java class with code that I thought would solve problem 9:

```
public class ProblemNine {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ProblemNine f = new ProblemNine();
        System.out.println(f.tripletP());

    }

    boolean isTriplet(int a, int b, int c){

        if((a*a)+(b*b)==(c*c)){
            return true;
        } else return false;    
    }

    int tripletP(){
        int a=1,b=2,c=997;
        int product = 0;

        //outerloop generates all possible combinations of 3 summators for the number 1000, if b>c>a is true
        outerloop:
        for(int i = 997; i>499; i--){
            c = i;
            b = 999-i;
            a = 1;

            while(b>(a+2) && (a+b) == (1000-i) && a!=b && c>b){
                b--;
                a++;
                // supposedly checks if a,b,c are a triplet.
                if (isTriplet(a,b,c)){
                    product=a*b*c;
                    break outerloop;
                }
            }   

            if(c>997 || b>499 || a>249){
                break outerloop;
            }
        }

        return product;
    }

}
```

Comment: `Math.pow()` uses floating point arithmetic, thus you cannot safely compare the results, as there might be slight differences. Simply use `a*a` to square ints.

Comment: `Math.pow` is really expensive and more verbose than `a*a`

Comment: In my other tries, I used a*a and the result was the same.

Comment: I suggest you step through the code in your debugger. BTW if `(a+b) == (1000 - c)` you can calculate that `a = 1000 - c - b`  You don't need to try every combination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(int i = 997; i>499; i--){
```

You're stopping too early. If `a<b<c` and `a+b+c == 1000`, the smallest possible value for c isn't 500, it's 335.

```
for(int i = 997; i>335; i--){
```

With this new lower bound, `b` will occasionally be larger than `c`, which will prematurely trigger some of your conditionals. You can remove them and still get the correct answer, though.

```
    for(int i = 997; i>335; i--){
        c = i;
        b = 999-i;
        a = 1;

        while(b>(a+2)){
            b--;
            a++;
            if (isTriplet(a,b,c)){
                product=a*b*c;
                break outerloop;
            }
        }
    }
```